# vscodeでemmet入力をしたらシングルクォーテーションで出力したい

Tags: vscode

vscodeでemmet入力をしているのですが、出力をシングルクォーテーションにしたいのでsettings.jsonにこのように書いています。

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "attr_quotes": "single"
    }
}
```

これで一応シングルにはなります。

例えばaと打ってtabキーを押すとこうなります。

```
<a href=''></a>
```

しかしclassやhrefから入力を始めたときはダブルクォーテーションになってしまいます。
例えばdivタグが既に書かれていてそこにclassを挿入する、あるいはaタグにhrefを挿入するのをemmetでやるとこういう風にダブルになってしまいます。

```
<div class="">
<a href="">
```

これを下記のようにシングルで出力させる方法はないでしょうか。

```
<div class=''>
<a href=''>
```

Comment: 自分の知る限りでは、Emmetはタグを補完する機能しかないので、classやhrefのみを挿入するのはVSCodeの機能もしくは別のプラグインの機能だと思います。そのため、Emmetの設定が反映されないのだろうと思います。https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/

Comment: こちらの投稿が参考になるのではないかと思います。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55897377/how-to-make-vscode-autocomplete-html-tags-attribute-with-single-quote

Comment: ありがとうございます。問題の部分はemmetじゃなくvscodeなんですね。リンク先については自分と同じ事象のようですが、更にその先も含めて辿ってみても結局解決されたのかどうかよくわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

classやhrefのみを挿入するのはEmmetの機能ではないので、それだけでは設定が不十分です（参考：Emmetの機能一覧（英語） https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/）。

`settings.json`に、以下を追記してみてください。

```js
"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"
```

もちろんEmmetの設定も必要です。

```js
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "attr_quotes": "single"
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。やってみましたが変化はありませんでした。テストファイルはtest.htmlとtest.blade.phpでやりました。

Comment: 先の設定はjavascriptの入力には有効でした。
test.jsで省略入力すると設定無しではダブル、有りではシングルにちゃんと切り替わりました。尚、私の目的とするファイルは.blade.phpです。(他に.phpや.cssも)

Comment: 検証不足で回答を投稿して申し訳ないです。調べてみたところ、順当な方法はすぐには見つからなかったのですが、Prettierで自動整形する場合にシングルクォートに自動で置き換える方法はあるようです。https://diwao.com/2019/09/vscode-prettier.html

Comment: 保存時に自動的にシングルに変換させるのも確かに手ですね。それでprettierを入れたのですが、どうも更にblade用のプラグインが必要みたいなのでいろいろ確認してみたいと思います。